# What is the name of this type of directed acyclic graph?

Tags: tree, graph, graph-theory, nomenclature, directed-graph

Perhaps it isnt even a DAG, but as its naming im after i wasnt sure what title to give this...

What is the name of a data structure where every node can only have 0 or 1 paths INTO it?
Strictly, is this a tree?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a directed tree.  Plain trees as such are undirected.

Your constraint isn't precisely how trees are defined (the definition of a tree is that any two vertices are connected by no more than one path), but it does constrain your graph to be a valid directed tree.  (Unless you want to employ weird usages of 'directed tree' that require a uniform tropism, which I can't say interests me.)

Comment: Per Bill the Lizard, it does require the acyclicity constraint.  I was assuming it from all the mentions, though it isn't actually in your final specification.

Comment: Yeah I meant acyclic, inferred from the title but i should have been more specific ;)

Answer (score 4):

Are there any other constraints?  From only the one you've given I can construct a graph that is *not* a tree.

A -> B -> A

If you add the constraint that the graph is acyclic, then it would be a tree.

Comment: How's that?  He can do A -> B -> { C, D, E }....  I feel like I must be missing something.

Comment: Oh, I see.  I thiiiink you're reading an implication of a constraint on outlinks.  But that seems impossible, since the only constraint you could read from OP's question would be zero outlinks, which would stop you from having a graph at all.

Comment: @chaos: I think you started writing your comment before I edited my answer.  I was missing something before the edit.

Comment: @chaos: Exactly right.  I was thinking 0 or 1 outlink, which is either a linked list or not a graph.